# Checking if "protected" links resolve

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-requests

I wrote a simple python script that goes over local HTML documents and text files and tries to check if all the links in them resolve.

Basically, something similar to this (very simplified):

```
import re, requests
with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
  for line in file:
    for m in re.finditer(r'https?://[^\s"]+', line):
      try:
        requests.head(m[0]).raise_for_status()
      except Exception as err:
        print(err)
```

Unfortunately, it does not work for links on Twitter (which requires the user to be logged in) and with some other sites that use captcha protection.

I also tried writing a small JS code inside the document but ran into CORS issues.

Can anyone help me overcome this issues?
Specifically for Twitter using the python script - how do I programmatically log in?

Answer (score -1):

Try add some headers into requests like

```
resp = requests.get(url, headers={'user-agent':'i am not a bot'})
```

just copy the headers from dev tools from a browser

Comment: Did it work for you?  It didn't work for me.  (Obviously I did add some headers to make things work for other sites, but twitter proved to be more tricky)

Comment: was just an idea, sometimes I try to avoid CORS using the original page of request and manipulate using a for into console to fetch all my urls using JS

Comment: I am not very familiar with JS.  An example would be appreciated.